# Primeiros passos: Ionic

Tags: android, ionic

- O que preciso aprender para criar apps com Ionic?
- Qual linguagem ele utiliza?
- Queria artigos que me mostra-se os primeiros passos.

Comment: Não entendo porque vocês ficam negativando essa pergunta. Isso estraga a comunidade. Qualquer um com as mesmas dúvidas chegará à essa pergunta pelo Google. Tendo em vista que a documentação do Ionic está em português, acho essa pergunta legítima. E apesar de ter alguns tutoriais em português de qualidade tratando sobre o assunto, a informação pode muito bem estar documentada dentro da comunidade stackoverflow.

Comment: No comentário acima leia-se "... documentação do Ionic NÃO está em português..."

Comment: @Brittz A questão é que, dependendo da pergunta, parece que não tem o mínimo de esforço para fazer uma pesquisa e ler um pouco mais a respeito. Não digo este caso, mas muita gente tem "preguiça" de fazer uma  boa pesquisa, quando na verdade estaria aprendendo muito mais sobre o assunto. Para você ter uma visão crítica, é necessário extrair informações de várias fontes, e não somente daqui do SO, talvez de uma resposta que qualquer pessoa pode dar. Faça um pequeno teste, cole a primeira pergunta na busca do Google, pegue somente os 3 primeiros resultados e reflita um pouco. É isso!!

Comment: @seamusd Concordo com você nesse sentido. Eu particularmente sempre uso os 3 primeiros resultados do Google. Se a pesquisa está difícil de concluir, no máximo os resultados da primeira página. No entanto, na maioria das vezes em que a resposta está no SO, já satisfaz a minha dúvida, porque as respostas costumam ser boas, ou as melhores são votadas. Por isso, mesmo que a pessoa não pesquise, só de fazer a pergunta já está contribuindo para a comunidade. Acho que essa pergunta atual é bem diferente de perguntas que querem apenas um copia e cola de código pronto.

Comment: @seamusd Para entender o meu ponto de vista, se essa pergunta tivesse sido respondida pelo mesmo usuário que a fez, seria justo ela ter sido negativada? Se a resposta é não, então a pergunta é legítima para o objetivo do site, que fica distorcida pelo uso dos usuários que tem pontuação alta.

Answer (score 3):

**Ionic**

O Ionic é um framework para desenvolvimento de [aplicativos híbridos](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/criando-aplicativos-hibridos-com-ionic-framework/) que funciona na maioria dos smartphones e tablets do mercado.

Ele nada mais é do que uma pilha de componentes e outros frameworks. Estes componentes são:

- Cordova: Integração com recursos nativos dos dispositivos
- AngularJS: Criação da parte Web da App
- Ionic Module e o Ionic CLI: Ferramentas e Componentes disponibilizados pelo framework

Antes de qualquer coisa, é necessário que você possua o NodeJS instalado.
Após instalar o NodeJS com sucesso, é indicado que adicione os SDK’s (Software Development Kit) da(s) plataforma(s) que deseja trabalhar (Android, iOS, Windows Phone).

**Instalando as ferramentas**

Rode o comando:

```
$ npm install -g cordova yo generator-angular generator-ionic ionic bower grunt
```

Esse comando por si só irá instalar o seguinte:

- Cordova/Phonegap
- Yeoman
- Gerador Yeoman para projetos AngularJS
- Ionic CLI (Command Line Tool)
- Bower
- Grunt

O parâmetro `-g` significa que esses comandos serão instalados globalmente, portanto será possível utiliza-los diretamente do terminal e não apenas na pasta em que se encontra.

**Criando o Projeto**

Após instalar as ferramentas você possui duas opções para criar um projeto utilizando o Ionic.

1. Diretamente pelo Ionic CLI
2. Utilizando o gerador Ionic do Yeoman.

As duas opções tem sua vantagem e com o tempo você irá conseguir identificar melhor qual utilizar.

**Ionic CLI**

A primeira opção é bem simples e contas na sessão de Passos Inicias do próprio site do Ionic. Basta fazer o seguinte:

Criar o app utilizando a linha de comando

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

Obs: `tabs` é um template pronto que irá criar um aplicativo com abas. As opções básicas são:

```
blank (Em branco) / tabs(Abas) / sidemenu (Menu Lateral)
```

Adicionar as plataformas desejadas e iniciar o emulador

```
$ cd myApp
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic build android
$ ionic run
```

**Generator-Ionic com Yeoman**

A segunda opção também foca na simplicidade e para iniciar o projeto com o gerador `yeoman` basta seguir os passos:

Criar um novo diretório e realizar um `cd`:

```
$ mkdir my-ionic-project && cd $_
```

A opção `$_` significa que irá usar o último parâmetro do último comando, no nosso caso o `nome/caminho` do diretório criado.

Executar `yo ionic`, passando de forma opcional o nome do App.

```
$ yo ionic [app-name]
```

A ferramenta de linha de comando do `Yeoman` irá oferecer uma série de perguntas. São elas:

- Deseja utilizar Sass com Compass? (Necessita Ruby instalado)
- Quais plugins do projeto cordova deseja incluir? (Nesse caso são plugins para utilizar as funcionalidades dos dispositivos como: Lista de contatos, câmera, gps, etc…)
- Deseja utilizar um template inicial? [T] são templates inicias (como os do último passo) e [A] aplicações de exemplo.

Após responder essas perguntas o `Yeoman` irá realizar todo o trabalho de baixar e instalar as dependências de acordo com as opções selecionadas.

**Degugando no Browser**

Para testar o aplicativo diretamente no browser basta executar o seguinte comando na pasta do projeto:

```
$ ionic serve
```

Caso tenha utilizado o `Yeoman`:

```
$ grunt serve
```

Uma nova aba/janela será aberta e qualquer alteração que realizar  no código será refletida pelo `live-reload`, excluindo a necessidade de executar o comando novamente.

**Debug com o Dispositivo**

Para realizar o `deploy` do dispositivo basta adicionar as plataformas desejadas(caso ainda não tenha adicionado), conectar o dispositivo ao computador e rodar os comandos `ionic/grunt`.

```
$ ionic run --device
```

ou

```
$ grunt run --device
```

**Artigos**:

- [Tutorial Ionic – Meu primeiro app](http://tableless.com.br/tutorial-ionic-meu-primeiro-app/)
- [Introdução ao Ionic Framework](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-ionic-framework/)
- [Criando uma aplicação com ionic](http://ticarpa.com.br/mobile/mobile-criando-uma-aplicacao-mobile-do-catalogo-de-imoveis-com-ionic/)
- [Iniciando com Ionic](https://lricoy.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/iniciando-com-ionic/)
- [Ionic Framework](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/criando-aplicativos-hibridos-com-ionic-framework/)
- [Getting Started](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)
- [Starting your app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Pré-Requisitos

Primeiramente você precisa ter conhecimento em:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. Javascript

Também é requerido AngularJS, mas se não souber, você pode ir aprendendo à medida que aprende a interagir com os recursos do Ionic. Porém, recomendo fortemente que você tente aprender AngularJS. Se você entende inglês, recomendo que use a própria [documentação](http://ionicframework.com/docs/) do Ionic para aprender a utilizá-lo, que é bem fácil. E no próprio site do [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) tem o [link](https://www.codeschool.com/pages/angular-1-vs-2) para um curso de Angular ministrado pela CodeShool.

### Instação

A instalação é muito fácil. Primeiro você instala o [Node](http://nodejs.org/). É só baixar o instalador e ir avançando. Depois instala o Cordova e o Ionic através do comando:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Esse comando deve ser executado no terminal do seu sistema operacional. Se estiver no Windows, é só abrir o cmd. Neste único comando você instala o Cordova e o Ionic. O parâmetro `-g` determina que a instalação será global.

Depois você precisa preparar o ambiente para Android e IOS, seguindo tutoriais específicos para cada. Mas isso pode ser feito depois, já que o Ionic pode emular o aplicativo no browser através de um comando especial.

### Criando um Projeto

Para criar um projeto você deve digitar no terminal:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

`myApp` é o nome do projeto. `tabs` é o template, que pode ser também `blank` (em branco) ou `sidemenu`.

Executando isso, o ionic irá criar os arquivos iniciais para o seu app.

### Executando o App no Navegador

```
ionic serve --lab
```

O parâmetro `--lab` fará exibir como ficará no IOS e no Android. Tente executar sem esse parâmetro para você ver a diferença.

### Artigo

[Este artigo](http://tableless.com.br/tutorial-ionic-meu-primeiro-app/) está em português e deixa bem claro os primeiros passos.

**Fonte:** [Documentação do Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/)